# Updating WPF DataGrid without firing OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have to do two-way communication using WPF on the client, and WCF to talk between server and client. There are three parts:

- The UI (which the user can type values into, the view in the MVVM pattern)
- The client code behind (the ViewModel in the MVVM pattern)
- The remote WCF server, which talks to the view model.

When the user types something into the UI, because of the two-way WPF databinding, the value gets updated in the view model. The view model fires the OnPropertyChanged event. Upon listening to this event, the view model informs the server of the change. **THIS IS OK!**

**GOING THE OTHER DIRECTION IS THE PROBLEM.** If the server gets updated, I expect the user to be able to see the change directly in the UI. The server sends the view model the data. The view model updates the property, so that the UI can display the value. But when setting this property, it fires the OnPropertyChanged event again, and the change gets sent to the server all over again. Think about it like this:

```
public int MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return myProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        // Essentially, I want to know how to tell when the code enters here from the client typing on the UI, or from the server.
        myProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}

public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    // send this property and its value to the server.
}
```

Comment: simple equalty check in property setters `set { if (_propValue == value) return; ... }` should prevent possible loops

Comment: It's generally a good idea to do an equality check in setters as Ash mentions. Raising xxxChanged events when nothing actually changed can be misleading.

Comment: This only solves part of my problem. If the user is updating the client from the UI, which updates the server, that works fine. The problem is when the server is updating the client, which displays on the UI. When the server gives a message back to the client, the client changes the property and fires the OnPropertyChanged Event in order to update the UI. But this same event also updates the server. I can't separate the two.

Comment: @user3685285 Sorry for the late reply. Please be aware that as the OP you are automatically notified of any new comments. However, other commenters are not unless you include their name with the [@Name syntax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: I would avoid calling external service on every propertychange, as it will result in 'chatty' interaction between client and service. I can see some other problems with this approach: if latency between client and service increases, you will see notification from previous changes overriding latest change.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the server and you're running < .Net 4.5 you probably have to resort to reflection and examining the call stack. Beginning with .Net 4.5 there are [Caller Information methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540(v=vs.110).aspx) that can help.

If you are able to modify the server then have it use a different method to set the value but raise `PropertyChanged` for the property the UI is bound to.

```
public int MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return myProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        // Essentially, I want to know how to tell when the code enters here from the client typing on the UI, or from the server.
        myProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}

public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    // send this property and its value to the server.
}

private void OnServerChangedMyProperty(int value)
{
    myProperty = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
}
```

---

**Update - because comments can't do code blocks**

Say you have 3 properties: `Sum`, `First` and `Second`. Whenever `First` or `Second` changes you also need to update `Sum`. So the setter for `First` looks like:

```
set
{
    _first = value;
    _sum = _first + _second;
    OnPropertyChanged("First"); //Update bindings to First
    OnPropertyChanged("Sum"); //Update bindings to Sum
}
```

and the setter for `Second` looks like:

```
set
{
    _second = value;
    _sum = _first + _second;
    OnPropertyChanged("Second"); //Update bindings to Second
    OnPropertyChanged("Sum");  //Update bindings to Sum
}
```

Comment: But I can only update the UI by setting the property it's bound to, which then triggers the message to the server. I don't know how to separate it out.